# How to measure the width of items in itemize environment?

Tags: lists, itemize, width

I want the output of the code below to be like this image. How to do this?
Please keep in mind that the width of [Foo Bar Foo]'s is variable. So it should be calculated automatically.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\noindent Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
\begin{itemize}
  \item[Foo] An item
  \item[Foo Bar Foo] An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item  
  \item[Bar Bar] An item 
\end{itemize}
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** I don't want to use tabular or similar environment, because there are many items which should span some pages.

Comment: simplest is to use a tabular rather than a list, or you could do like bibitem and have an option to give the widest label, or you need two passes and save the widest label in the aux file to align on a second pass

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Please see my edit.

Comment: longtable package?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Isn't there any other way to solve this problem? I don't have pleasant experience with tabular-like environment.

Comment: yes as I say you can do a two pass solution to record the widest entry, I may post something in a bit of noone else has

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have dangerous things like labels or counter settings (numbered equations, for instance) in the body of the `itemize`, you can locally redefine `\item` to do the measurement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,environ}

\newlength{\xitemlenx}
\newlength{\xitemleny}
\NewEnviron{xitemize}{%
  \setbox0=\vbox{
    \xitemlenx=0pt
    \def\item[##1]{\measureitem{##1}}
    \BODY
    \global\xitemleny\xitemlenx
  }%
  \itemize[
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\xitemleny+\labelsep,
    labelwidth=\xitemleny,
    align=left
  ]
  \BODY
  \enditemize
}
\newcommand{\measureitem}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}%
  \ifdim\dimen0>\xitemlenx
    \xitemlenx=\dimen0
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
\begin{xitemize}
  \item[Foo] An item
  \item[Foo Bar Foo] An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item  
  \item[Bar Bar] An item 
\end{xitemize}
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need a single item, as you seem to from your comments, it's easier because just one label needs to be measured; here's the idea, integrated in the previous code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,environ}

\newlength{\xitemlenx}
\newlength{\xitemleny}
\NewEnviron{xitemize}{%
  \setbox0=\vbox{
    \xitemlenx=0pt
    \def\item[##1]{\measureitem{##1}}
    \BODY
    \global\xitemleny\xitemlenx
  }%
  \itemize[
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\xitemleny+\labelsep,
    labelwidth=\xitemleny,
    align=left
  ]
  \BODY
  \enditemize
}
\newcommand{\measureitem}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}%
  \ifdim\dimen0>\xitemlenx
    \xitemlenx=\dimen0
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\singleitem}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\xitemleny}{#1}%
  \begin{itemize}[
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\xitemleny+\labelsep,
    labelwidth=\xitemleny,
    align=left
  ]
  \item[#1]\textbf{#2}
  \end{itemize}%
}

\begin{document}

Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
\begin{xitemize}
  \item[Foo] An item
  \item[Foo Bar Foo] An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item  
  \item[Bar Bar] An item 
\end{xitemize}
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
Now a single item:
\singleitem{Foo Bar}{An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item}
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one thing: for simplicity, I've defined a command named `mycmd` as `\newcommand{\mycmd}[2]{%
\begin{xitemize}
\item[#1] \textbf{#2}
\end{xitemize}
‎}‎‎‎` and I use it as `\mycmd{...}{...}` in the body, but it doesn't work. Could you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: @Sisabe What's the purpose of this command?

Comment: it is the equivalent of the below: `\begin{xitemize}
\item[Foo]\textbf{An item} 
‎\end{xitemize}‎`

Comment: Actually, the real `mycmd` is more complicated and I've simplified that here to be a MWE.

Comment: @Sisabe If you have a single `\item`, you just need to measure its argument: much less complication. I'll add it to my answer; please tell me if it doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I have more than 200 items (more than 10 pages). Sorry if I'm new in LaTeX.

Comment: @Sisabe So, what should `\mycmd` do? Just use the `xitemize` environment around the items.

Comment: "what should \mycmd do?" I want it just for simplicity. Isn't it possible to use `mycmd` instead of using `xitemize` environment in the document body? Please help me!

Comment: @Sisabe Sorry, but I can't understand. If you want that the item text is aligned, you need to measure *all* the labels beforehand, so you can't typeset them one at a time; therefore you need *one* environment containing the whole text. Besides, what would be the advantage of `\mycmd{label}{text}` over `\item[label] text`?

Comment: Ok, you are right. I'll use `\item[label] text` then. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

With the `ltablex` package, wich combines the functionalities of `tabularx`  and `longtable`, it's very easy:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, ltablex}

\begin{document}
\noindent Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line. Text text text text tex text text text tex.

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\quad}X@{}}
 Foo & An item \\
Foo Bar Foo & An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item An item\\
Bar Bar & An item
\end{tabularx}
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line. Text text text text tex text text text tex.

\end{document}
```

[image]